# Why do I need curly braces for nested JSX, even if it is working without it

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

If I have this code

```
var myDiv = <div>
               <h1>Hello World</h1>
            </div>
```

which is working as same as this

```
 var myDiv = {<div>
                   <h1>Hello World</h1>
              </div>}
```

then why do I exactly need the braces?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> then why do I exactly need the braces?

You don't, your first snippet is just fine *(other than the missing semicolon at the end :-) )*. In fact, your second example won't compile.

If you meant `()`, not `{}`, you may be referring to [the React documentation's suggestion that you use `()` around things like that](https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html#embedding-expressions-in-jsx). As it says in the docs, that's purely to avoid an automatic semicolon insertion hazard. There is no ASI hazard in an assignment like your code, but there is when using `return`:

```
// Works
return (
    <div>
        <h1>Hello World</h1>
    </div>
);

// Also works
return <div>
        <h1>Hello World</h1>
    </div>;

// Also works
const div =
    <div>
        <h1>Hello World</h1>
    </div>;
return div;

// FAILS
return
    <div>
        <h1>Hello World</h1>
    </div>;
```

That last one fails because ASI inserts a semicolon after the `return` and before the JSX, making your function not return anything.

Comment: I wish the JSX docs mentioning ‘you should always use parenthesis to avoid issues with ASI’ had actually *explained* it, as you had, instead of assuming everybody wants to spam their source with unnecessary syntax. Thank you!